# How I can retaining cookies with each request

Tags: node.js, cookies, mocha.js, chai, chai-http

I'm new on mocha and chai.

I'm writing integration test cases into NodeJS application using mocha and chai.

I was looking for a common solution.

Here I'm explaining what I'm doing.

In short, my point is

**How to retain cookies to each request**

My node server is running on the separate machine on port 3000 and Test Cases will be on another machine.

**This is my application directory structure**

[image]

**First, login API test case**

```
 let chai = require('chai');
 let chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
 let expect = require('chai').expect;

 chai.use(chaiHttp);

 let agent = chai.request.agent(endpoint);

 describe('/POST login ', function () {
 it(' login ', function (done) {
    let req = {
        'email': 'email',
        'password': 'password'
    };
    agent
        .post(login)
        .send(req)
        .then(function (response) {
            expect(response).to.have.status(200);
            done();
        }).catch(function (error) {
            done(error);
        });
    });
});
```

**Second, to get account list**

```
let chai = require('chai');
let chaiHttp = require("chai-http");

let expect = chai.expect;
chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('/POST account', function () {
    it(' Account List ', async function () {
    let response = await chai.request(endpoint)
        .post(accounts)
    try {
        expect(response).to.have.status(200);
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
});
});
```

I've created separate files for each module.

Well,

All APIs are authenticated based on the session.

So,

Is there any way to set cookies globally on chai-http plugin?

Basically,

Login test case will set the cookie and after that, each request will carry this cookie.

Thanks